# R X axis labels overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a simple line graph in R which uses time stamps for the X axis. The problem is that R is attempting to display each one of these time stamps which is causing them to overlap with one another. I want the graph to only display a few of the X axis labels so its readable and not a garbled mess.[image: The Graph in Question]

Comment: I am pretty sure that an answer exists somewhere here in SO. However, can you provide a code and data set to enable us to reproduce your problem? You can paste the output of `dput(df)`, where df is your data frame, into your post.

Comment: seems like your x-axis is a factor?  getting that column into the proper time-date class is a good start.  then `scale_x_continuous` should let you control what is displayed.

Comment: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-axis-ticks-a-guide-to-customize-tick-marks-and-labels

Comment: See `coord_flip` or you could adjust the axis labels `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

Comment: @tyluRp This solution fixed the graph for me

Comment: Nice, glad it worked out